# Append variables to dataframe in a loop + R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, append

I am running a mixed effects model in a loop in R and want to create a dataframe that appends the results of certain variables each iteration. I am trying to achieve this using `cbind` and setting the row values to the results of each iteration of the loop.

The problem I am having is that after I run the loop only the last set of variables are being stored in the dataframe. In the executable example below the `results` variable is where I am trying to build the dataframe.

```
library(nlme)

data(mtcars)

mtcars

names <- colnames(mtcars)

names_mdl <- c("cyl",  "disp", "hp",   "drat")

for (n in names_mdl){
  print(n)
  exp <- mtcars[,n]
  print(exp)
  
  # linear mixed effects model
  mlme <- lme(mpg ~ exp, random = ~ 1|cyl, data = mtcars, control = lmeControl(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000))
  
  # summarize the model results
  sum <- summary(mlme)
  print(sum)
  
  conf <- intervals(mlme, level = 0.95, which = 'fixed')
  print(conf)
  
  lower <- conf$fixed["exp","lower"]
  upper <- conf$fixed["exp","upper"]
  
  pvals <- data.frame(coef(sum))
  pvals
  p <- pvals$p.value[2]
  
  results <- data.frame(cbind("Explanatory Variable" = n,
                              "Lower Conf Int" = lower,
                              "Upper Conf Int" = upper,
                              "P Value" = p)
  )
  
}
```

Is there another append function or something similar? I am more familiar with python and am struggling to find the R syntax for this.

Comment: When you do `results <- ...` it overwrites the `results` object entirely. Before the loop, initialize a `results` as a list, `results <- list()`. Inside the loop put your data in a named element of the `results` list, `results[[n]] <- data.frame("Explanatory Variables" = n, ...)`. After the loop, transform your list into a data frame, `results_df <- do.call(rbind, results)`.

Comment: Also, avoid `data.frame(cbind())`. `cbind()` creates a `matrix` by default, which if you mix classes can result in some bad casting. Just use `data.frame()` directly, you don't need the `cbind()` here. (`cbind()` is great for combining 2 data frames by putting them side by side. It's not great at creating a data frame from scratch.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you create your `results` object inside the for loop. You have to create it outside of the loop in order for the results to be appended as a new column each time, something like

```
results <- list()
```

or

```
results <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(names_mdl))
```

(Sometimes the `list` command doesn't work as planned when I use it in loops)

Then run your for loop, but change the line where the results are appended to

```
results[[n]] <- cbind("Explanatory Variable" = rep(n, length(lower)),
                              "Lower Conf Int" = lower,
                              "Upper Conf Int" = upper,
                              "P Value" = p)
```

Then, after the for loop, you'll have to merge all of these list items into a data.frame. For this, you can use

```
df_results <- do.call("cbind", results)
```

--outside of the for loop--

Although if you're open to data.table (which is faster and uses a more python-like syntax), you can use the `cbindlist` command:

```
dt_results <- cbindlist(results)
```

Basically what happens is that R won't understand if you try to append a bunch of columns at the same time. You need to save each of the matrices in a list, then bind the elements of the list together later. Hope this helps.